# "error: Grunt :: Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:xxxx failed: address already in use"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, gruntjs, sails.js

am trying to run two separate projects at the same time.

two separate projects are sailsjs applications.

using visual studio code.

i would like to start each of these projects in vscode "debug mode".

each of these projects need to run on different ports.

In the local.js of each of these projects I have mentioned:

```
module.exports = {
   port: xx
}
```

yet only one of my projects seems to run correctly.

i did a bit of looking around. i think i have to add some kind of arguments to my `launch.json`, which I did so:

`"runtimeArgs": ["--inspect=9230"]`

but still i get the error:

```
"2019-03-05T11:31:25.085Z - error: Grunt :: Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:9985 failed: address already in use"
```

when i restart one of the applications. the other application seem to be running fine.

from this error, i understand there is some kind of grunt module that generates a random port to the debugging host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port defined in `local.js` is project port, `sails inspect` use [default](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) port for debug `127.0.0.1:9229`.

So when u try `sails inspect` in both project, first project will take default port, and then second will fail.

Sails [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-inspect) say "To use the standard (command-line) node debugger with sails, you can always just run `node inspect app.js`", then u can use command `node inspect --port=xxxx app.js`.

Example:

Project A:

```
module.exports = {
   port: 2000
}

node inspect --port=9980 app.js
```

Project B:

```
module.exports = {
   port: 2001
}

node inspect --port=9981 app.js
```

I hope this is what u need.

Comment: I had a couple of other issues, which were resolved and then I was able to run different projects under different ports using these settings. Thanks!